# Determine the number of ordered triple $(x, y, z)$ of integer numbers (negatives and positives) satisfying $|x| + |y| + |z| \le 6$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine the number of ordered triple $(x, y, z)$ of integer numbers (negatives and positives) satisfying $|x| + |y| + |z| \le 6$

I know that final answer is 377, but how?

**Edit:**

Drawing from [David K's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3157416):

> One way to count the ways is to first do the ways for which $x > 0,$ $y > 0,$ and $z > 0.$
>   That's the number of ways to put $6$ or fewer indistinguishable balls into $3$ numbered bins under the constraint that every bin must have at least one ball,
>   which is the number of ways to put $3$ or fewer indistinguishable balls in $3$ numbered bins without that constraint, which is the number of ways of putting exactly $3$ indistinguishable balls in $4$ numbered bins.
>   Multiply by $8$ to take into account all the cases where $x < 0$ or $y < 0$ or $z < 0.$

$x,y,z >0 => x + y + z <= 3, n = Cr(3+4-1,3) * (8) = 160$

> Now let $x = 0,$ $y > 0,$ and $z > 0.$
>   Count the number of ways to put up to $6$ balls in $2$ bins if each bin must contain at least one ball. Multiply by four to account for all the cases were $y < 0$ or $z < 0.$ Multiply that result by $3$ to account for the fact that we could have chosen $y= 0$ or $z=0$ instead of $x = 0.$

$x=0, x,y>0 => y+z <=6, n = Cr(4+3-1, 4) * 3 * 14 = 180$

> Now let $x = y = 0$ and $z > 0.$ There are $6$ ways for that to happen. Multiply by $2$ to account for $z < 0,$ then by $3$ to account for the other choices of which variables are zeros.

$x,y = 0, z>0 => z<=6, n = 6 * 2 * 3 = 36$

$x,y,z=0, n = 1$

Sum of all of them is : 160 + 180 + 36 + 1 = 377

Comment: I don't see how you can get to $377$ with just negatives and positives. Are you sure that zeroes are allowed?

Comment: I am sure the answer is 377, because I have it from a book, but I don't know how they reach to this answer as well.

Comment: @bof Good point. My Python says disallowing zeroes reduces the number of solutions to $160$, while allowing them gets $377$.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: @Esmaeil: what book? What topics are covered in the section where this question arose? Have you tried anything? perhaps the number of pairs that sum to less than or equal to $m$?

Comment: @Esmaeil: I have written an answer, but unless there is more context provided, it would not be in the best interests of the site, as explained in [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959), to post the answer.

Comment: This is an test question, I find the answer key, but not solution. It must be solve with recursive methods. Thanks of all.

Comment: And Thanks @robjohn, This is my first question. I will read your suggested document (how to ask a good question) it is very useful

Comment: I have moved the attempt from the comment to David K's answer to the question. This seemed to be enough context that I undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to count the ways is to first do the ways for which $x > 0,$ $y > 0,$ and $z > 0.$
That's the number of ways to put $6$ or fewer indistinguishable balls into $3$ numbered bins under the constraint that every bin must have at least one ball,
which is the number of ways to put $3$ or fewer indistinguishable balls in $3$ numbered bins without that constraint, which is the number of ways of putting exactly $3$ indistinguishable balls in $4$ numbered bins.
Multiply by $8$ to take into account all the cases where $x < 0$ or $y < 0$ or $z < 0.$

Now let $x = 0,$ $y > 0,$ and $z > 0.$
Count the number of ways to put up to $6$ balls in $2$ bins if each bin must contain at least one ball. Multiply by four to account for all the cases were $y < 0$ or $z < 0.$ Multiply that result by $3$ to account for the fact that we could have chosen $y= 0$ or $z=0$ instead of $x = 0.$

Now let $x = y = 0$ and $z > 0.$ There are $6$ ways for that to happen. Multiply by $2$ to account for $z < 0,$ then by $3$ to account for the other choices of which variables are zeros.

Finally add $1$ for the case $x = y = z = 0,$ which was not covered by any of the other cases.

The total will be $377$ if you do all these calculations correctly.

Comment: 1. $x,y,z >0 => x + y + z <= 3, n = Cr(3+4-1,3) * (8) = 160$  as explained in paragraph one

2. $x=0, x,y>0 => y+z <=6, n = Cr(4+3-1, 4) * 3 * 14 = 180$  as explained in paragraph two

3. $x,y = 0, z>0 => z<=6, n = 6 * 2 * 3 = 36$ as explained in paragraph three

4. $x,y,z=0, n = 1$

Sum of all of them is : 160 + 180 + 36 + 1 = 377

Comment: paragraph one *where*? paragraph two *where*? paragraph three *where*? This information should be included in the question, not simply a comment to an answer.

Comment: I write in comment, because I try @David method. But he did not calculate it himself then I do to show he find correct method.

Comment: @Esmaeil: Oh, I see. These are paragraphs in David K's answer. I didn't understand before. Good! Adding this to your question to show your attempt would be very good.

Comment: @Esmaeil: It is pretty important that you add this attempt as context to the question; otherwise, the question may be closed (there is already one close vote) and possibly deleted.

Comment: I have moved the attempt to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is $f(6)$ where $f(n)$ for integers $n\ge0$ is the number of lattice
points in the polyhedron $nP$. This is the $n$-fold dilate of $P$, the polyhedron with vertices $(\pm1,0,0)$, $(0,\pm1,0)$ and $(0,0,\pm1)$. By [Ehrhart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial), $f$ is a degree $3$ polynomial in $n$. Moreover, its leading coefficient is the volume of $P$, namely $\frac43$. We also have $f(0)=1$
and $f(1)=7$. But by Macdonald's reciprocity law $f(-n)$ is the negative
of the number of lattice points in the interior of $nP$, so that $f(-1)=-1$.
The only polynomial satisfying all these conditions is
$$f(n)=\frac43n^3+2n^2+\frac83n+1.$$
Then $f(6)=377$.

Answer (score 0):

Try it first for the 2-dimensional $(x, y)$-plane and for smaller upper bounds: $|x| + |y| \leq 1$, then  $|x| + |y| \leq 2$, then $|x| + |y| \leq 3$.  In each case, sketch a picture.

Now try it in the $(x, y, z)$-space, with smaller upper bounds: $|x| + |y| + |z| \leq 1$, then $|x| + |y| + |z| \leq 2$, etc..  Sketch a picture in every case.

By the time you are up to $|x| + |y| + |z| \leq 3$, you will be seeing enough of a pattern to solve your problem--maybe even much earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force solution. Letters $x,y,z$ stand for nonzero integers.

**Case 1.** Permutations of $(x,x,x)$.
$(1,1,1)$
$(2,2,2)$
$2$ combinations, one permutation of each, $2^3=8$ ways to assign $\pm$ signs, so $2\cdot1\cdot8=\boxed{16}$ solutions.

**Case 2.** Permutations of $(x,x,y)$, $x\ne y$.
$(1,1,2)$
$(1,1,3)$
$(1,1,4)$
$(2,2,1)$
$4$ combos, $3$ perms each, $2^3=8$ sign choices, so $4\cdot3\cdot8=\boxed{96}$ solutions.

**Case 3.** Perms of $(x,y,z)$ with $x,y,z$ all different.
$(1,2,3)$
Just $1$ combo, $6$ perms, $8$ sign choices, so $1\cdot6\cdot8=\boxed{48}$ solutions.

**Case 4.** Perms of $(x,x,0)$.
$(1,1,0)$
$(2,2,0)$
$(3,3,0)$
$3$ combos, $3$ perms each, $2^2=4$ sign choices, so $3\cdot3\cdot4=\boxed{36}$ solutions.

**Case 5.** Perms of $(x,y,0)$, $x\ne y$.
$(1,2,0)$
$(1,3,0)$
$(1,4,0)$
$(1,5,0)$
$(2,3,0)$
$(2,4,0)$
$6$ combos, $6$ perms each, $4$ sign choices, so $6\cdot6\cdot4=\boxed{144}$ solutions.

**Case 6.** Perms of $(x,0,0)$.
$(1,0,0)$
$(2,0,0)$
$(3,0,0)$
$(4,0,0)$
$(5,0,0)$
$(6,0,0)$
$6$ combos, $3$ perms each, $2$ sign choices, so $6\cdot3\cdot2=\boxed{36}$ solutions.

**Case 7.** Perms of $(0,0,0)$.
$(0,0,0$.
Just $1\cdot1\cdot1=\boxed{1}$ solution

The final answer is
$$16+96+48+36+144+36+1=\boxed{377}$$
**provided** $0$'s are allowed. However, if you really mean "negatives and positives" (no $0$'s) then you only get
$$16+96+48=\boxed{160}$$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_{n,m}$ be the number of $n$-tuples of integers so that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|\le m\tag1
$$
Pretty simply, we have
$$
a_{1,m}=2\binom{m}{1}+\binom{m}{0}\tag2
$$
Furthermore, we have the recurrence
$$
\begin{align}
a_{n+1,m}
&=\overbrace{\quad a_{n,m}\quad\vphantom{\sum_1^m}}^\text{$0$ in position $n+1$}+\overbrace{2\sum_{k=1}^ma_{n,m-k}}^\text{$\pm k$ in position $n+1$}\\
&=a_{n,m}+2\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}a_{n,k}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
a_{2,m}=4\binom{m}{2}+4\binom{m}{1}+\binom{m}{0}\tag4
$$
and
$$
a_{3,m}=8\binom{m}{3}+12\binom{m}{2}+6\binom{m}{1}+\binom{m}{0}\tag5
$$
In general, we get by induction, using $(2)$ and $(3)$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{k}{j}=\binom{n}{j+1}$,
$$
a_{n,m}=\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k}\tag6
$$
Plugging in $n=3$ and $m=6$ gives
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{a_{3,6}=377}\tag7
$$

---

I just came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409696) which proves
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{m+k}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k}
$$

Comment: I have undeleted my answer because the OP has provided context in a comment to David K's answer. I have prompted the OP to include that effort in the question.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? This answer answers the question and more.

Comment: Since no explanation was given for the recent downvote (10 months after the last activity on this question), I have expanded the discussion above. If the downvote was for some other reason, it would be nice to know that reason.