# Sum of non-negative integers less than a given integer?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, polynomials

Let $N \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and let $\alpha = (a_1,...,a_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^{n}$.

I am interested in the cardinality of the set ${\{\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^{n} : |\alpha| \leq N}\}$, where $|\alpha| = a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n$.

Does anyone know how to prove this? I assume there is some sort of combinatorial argument but I'm stuck? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: @RossMillikan It was supposed to be non-negative integers, thank you.

Comment: You might be able to adapt the approach from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3157473).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A(n, N)$ be your number. Define $A_r(n, N)$ to be the cardinality of the set
$$
\{\alpha\in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}^n\mid |\alpha|\leq N, a_n = r\}
$$
Clearly, we have
$$
A(n, N) = \sum_{r = 0}^N A_r(n, N)
$$
Also, note that by simply removing the last element of $\alpha$, we have
$$
A_r(n, r) = A(n-1, N-r)
$$
which is to say
$$
A(n, N) = \sum_{r = 0}^N A(n-1, N-r)
$$
Comparing the sum for $A(n, N)$ and the sum for $A(n, N-1)$, we get 
$$
A(n, N) = A(n-1, N) + A(n, N-1)
$$
and we see that these are just relabelled binomial cefficients:
$$
A(n, N) = \binom{n+N}{N}
$$

Comment: By the stars and bars method, the number of  non-negative $n$-tuples which sum to $N$ is $\binom{N+n -1}{N}$? This is the number you've worked out for the cardinality of my set? But the cardinality of my set must be bigger than this right?

Comment: It must? Have you checked? For $n = 1$ or $n = 2$ it should be a simple thing to count by hand and compare.

Comment: My set includes the case where the non-negative $n$-typles sum to $N$. But it also includes the non-negative $n$-tuples which sum to $0,1,...,N-1$.

Comment: @theman You're right. I'm off by 1 somewhere. Let me just recheck my calculations.

Comment: @theman There we go. I had the wrong base case ($n = 0$ is valid, and $A(0,N) = 1$), and also I hadn't looked thoroughly enough at my sums. Now it should be correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  for $\alpha = N$ you are looking for weak compositions of $N$ into $n$ parts.  You can solve that with the usual stars and bars argument.  Now just sum the number of compositions of $k$ from $0$ to $N$

Comment: So, the answer is the value of the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom{k+n-1}{n-1}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: That sum is $\binom{N+n}{n}$, which matches Arthur's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this as putting $N$ items into $n+1$ bins, where $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are the contents of the first $n$ bins. Using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), this gives $\binom{N+n}{n}$.